# Apache Hive: Renaming columns of type array<struct<>>

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a transactional table say:

```
        CREATE TABLE Test(
         `name` string,
         `tracking_id` string,
          `actions`    array<struct<call:string,score:int,decision:string>>)
       PARTITIONED BY (
          `year` int,
          `month` int,
          `day` int)
       CLUSTERED BY (
           tracking_id)
       INTO 6 BUCKETS
       STORED AS ORC
       TBLPROPERTIES (
         'orc.compress'='ZLIB',
         'orc.compression.strategy'='SPEED',
         'orc.create.index'='true',
         'orc.encoding.strategy'='SPEED',
         'transactional'='true');
```

I have a bunch of data in the table

On doing `select * from test limit 1;`

```
0: jdbc:hive2://hive-server-two:10000> select * from test;
+------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--+
| test.name  | test.tracking_id  |                  test.actions                  | test.year  | test.month  | test.day  |
+------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--+
| User25     | 25                | [{"call":"put","score":100,"decision":"win"}]  | 2019       | 9           | 26        |
+------------+-------------------+------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------+-----------+--+
```

I now want to rename the column `actions` to `play`

`alter table test change actions play array<struct<call:string,score:int,decision:string>>;`

Now if when I run `select play from test limit 1`

```
+-------+--+
|  play |
+-------+--+
| NULL  |
+-------+--+
```

Is there a reason for this? How do I simply rename the column?

Answer (score 0):

We are [not allowed](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-add-a-field-to-a-complex-type-in-Alter-Table/td-p/38068) to alter column with Complex Types type and in example you shared is have complex data type.

Note: **Complex Types**

```
arrays: ARRAY<data_type>
maps: MAP<primitive_type, data_type> 
structs: STRUCT<col_name : data_type >
union: UNIONTYPE<data_type, data_type, ...>
```